# how to interpret this double summation, the first from i=1 and the second from j does not equal i

Tags: summation

I'm not sure what the meaning of the double sum is in this formula.
[image: photo]

Comment: I think it is more common and clearer to represent the second sum as $$\sum_{j=1\\j \neq i}^N$$  where it is clear you sum over all the $j$s that are not equal to $i$

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If for instance $N=3$, you consider the terms s.t. $(i,j)=(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)$

Comment: thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

This notation is not really acceptable as it mixes two different conventions: the first summation specifies a range, while the second does not (it merely excludes the combinations with $i=j$).

I would have preferred one of

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1\\j\ne i}^n$$ or $$\sum_i\sum_{j\ne i}$$

This said, it is equivalent to

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}+\sum_{j=i+1}^n\right)$$

Comment: thank you for answering